# Running NHibernate's unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, nhibernate, automated-tests

I have the latest NHibernate trunk, and I keep my builds of it up to date for use in my project, and everything is good.  However, NHibernate has bugs that I would like le to fix, or at least provide working unit tests to include in the source.  My problem is that I can't get the NHibernate unit tests to run, at all, and I have no idea where to start.  I have posted dozens of questions on the official boards relating to my problem, and have yet to receive a response.  Does anyone here know how I can get this stuff working ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **After** you have built the project through the NAnt build-scripts, open the NHibernate.Everything.sln solution in the ./src folder
2. Find the NHibernate.Test project
3. If you use SqlExpress go and create a database named nhibernate that your user has access to... if you use SQLServer go open up App.config and edit the connection string to use this instead - and then go create the database.
4. If you use ReSharper: Right click on NHibernate.Test project and click Run Unit Tests and...
5. If you don't use ReSharper then open Props for the NHibernate.Test project, go to the Debug pane and in the field "Start external program" browse to .\Tools\nunit and select nunit.exe. In the "Command Line Arguments" field enter NHibernate.Test.dll. Press Ctrl+F5 and...
6. Enjoy the green lights :)

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you.  My life just got 1000 times easier!